# String parsing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string

When I have `pf:/Abc/def/`, how can I get the `/Abc/def/`?

With Python, I can use

```
string = 'pf:/Abc/def/'
string.split(':')[1]
```

or even

```
string[3:]
```

What's the equivalent function in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pf:/Abc/def/"];
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
NSString *string2 = (NSString*) [components objectAtIndex:1];
```

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:

componentsSeparatedByString will return an NSArray. You grab the object at a certain index, and type cast it to NSString when storing it into another variable.

Comment: I get 'invalid initializer' at line 3 (NSString string2 = ...)